# Add Icon next to KeyEvent in JMenuItem

Tags: java, user-interface, icons, imageicon, jmenuitem

I have a problem with adding icon to the JMenuItem. I saw constructor`new JMenuItem (text, icon)` but I already used `new JMenuItem (text, mnemonic)`.

Part of my code:

```
file = new JMenu("File");
file.addMenuListener(this);
menuBar.add (file);

open = new JMenuItem("Open", KeyEvent.VK_O);
open.addActionListener(this);
open.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
Image img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().GetResource("C:img/openIcon.ico")).GetImage();
open.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img)); // That part returns Null Pointer Exception
file.add(open);
```

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: In the line starting `Image img = ...`, does it really say `.GetResource` and `.GetImage` with uppercase G's?  Shouldn't even be able to compile like that.

Comment: And that resource name "C:img/openIcon.ico" looks a little suspicious, too.